# How can i center content with active sidebar

Tags: html, css, web, center, centering

Please guys help me ... The sidebar will be allways active so i need to center the content on the webpage such as the highlighted text. The problem is that it's centered with width of the whole page counting the sidebar. can i divide the the widths somehow? the sidebar is made in bootstrap it's made with cols so i dont know the exact width.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can post your code, but the general idea would be for you to place a `div` next to sidenav (to the right), you can do that by setting the `margin-left` to the width of the `sidenav` and center the text in that `div`